# Do these solutions actually amount to a solution over the Reals and not over the Complexes as Mathematica says?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, number-theory

The following program outputs approximations to ZetaZero[1] and ZetaZero[-1]:

```
Clear[f, A, B, x, n, k, s, rho];
f[x_] := Zeta[x];
A[n_, s_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/f[s + k/n - 1/n], {k, 1, n}]
B[n_, s_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^(k - 1)*Binomial[n - 1, k - 1]/f[s + k/n], {k, 1, n}]
n = 30;
s = 14*I;
rho = s + 1/(1 - A[n, s]/B[n, s]);
N[%, n]
rho = -s + 1/(1 - B[n, s]/A[n, s]);
N[%, n]
Clear[f, A, B, x, n, k, s, rho];
Reduce[rho == s + 1/(1 - A/B) && 
  s + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s + 1/(1 - B/A)], Re[rho], Complexes]
```

0.5000000000000000000000000000 + 14.1347251417346937904572519836 I

0.5000000000000000000000000000 - 14.1347251417346937904572519836 I

as well as the solutions for Re[rho] over the Complexes given by the `Reduce[]` command:

```
(B == 0 && ((Re[A] < 0 && 
       Re[s] == (Im[A]^2 + Re[A]^2)/(2 Im[A]^2 + 2 Re[A]^2) && 
       rho == I Im[s] + Re[s]) || (Re[A] == 
        0 && ((Im[A] < 0 && Re[s] == 1/2 && 
           rho == 1/2 + I Im[s]) || (Im[A] > 0 && Re[s] == 1/2 && 
           rho == 1/2 + I Im[s]))) || (Re[A] > 0 && 
       Re[s] == (Im[A]^2 + Re[A]^2)/(2 Im[A]^2 + 2 Re[A]^2) && 
       rho == I Im[s] + Re[s]))) || (((Im[rho] < Im[s] && 
       Re[rho] == 1/2
        && (Re[B] < 0 || (Re[B] == 0 && (Im[B] < 0 || Im[B] > 0)) ||
          Re[B] > 0)) || (Im[rho] == 
        Im[s] && ((Re[s] < 1/2 && 
           Re[rho] == 1/2
            && (Re[B] < 
              0 || (Re[B] == 0 && (Im[B] < 0 || Im[B] > 0)) || 
             Re[B] > 0)) || (Re[s] > 1/2 && 
           Re[rho] == 1/2
            && (Re[B] < 
              0 || (Re[B] == 0 && (Im[B] < 0 || Im[B] > 0)) || 
             Re[B] > 0)))) || (Im[rho] > Im[s] && 
       Re[rho] == 1/2
        && (Re[B] < 0 || (Re[B] == 0 && (Im[B] < 0 || Im[B] > 0)) ||
          Re[B] > 0))) && A == (-B + B rho - B s)/(rho - s))
```

But entering the following line in Wolfram Alpha:

```
Reduce[rho == s + 1/(1 - A/B) &&    s + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s + 1/(1 - B/A)], rho]
```

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5Brho+%3D%3D+s+%2B+1%2F%281+-+A%2FB%29+%26%26++++s+%2B+1%2F%281+-+A%2FB%29+%3D%3D+Conjugate%5B-s+%2B+1%2F%281+-+B%2FA%29%5D%2C+rho%5D)

Gives the solutions over the Reals:

```
ρ = 1/2 and A<B and s = (A + B)/(2 A - 2 B)
ρ = 1/2 and A>B and s = (A + B)/(2 A - 2 B)
```

> So is the solution that Mathematica gives over the Complexes actually
> a solution over the Reals and not the Complexes?

Comment: The latex should have line breaks, but I don't know how to add them.

Comment: I will delete the latex

Comment: `Re[rho] == 1/2` in the output is what I find interesting.

Comment: It might make sense to recast with complex-valued variables and parameters split into explicit real and imaginary parts. Then solving over the `Reals` can be done.

Comment: Do you mean something like: `Reduce[rho == s1 + 1/(1 - (a1 + a2*I)/(b1 + b2*I)) && 
  s1 + 1/(1 - (a1 + a2*I)/(b1 + b2*I)) ==  Conjugate[-s2 + 1/(1 - (x1 + x2*I)/(y1 + y2*I))], Re[rho]]`

Comment: Or alternatively: `Reduce[rho == s1 + 1/(1 - (a1 + a2*I)/(b1 + b2*I)) && 
  s1 + 1/(1 - (a1 + a2*I)/(b1 + b2*I)) ==  Conjugate[-s2 + 1/(1 - (x1 + x2*I)/(y1 + y2*I))], rho]`

Comment: I mean something along these lines. `sys = {rho == s + 1/(1 - A/B), 
  s + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s + 1/(1 - B/A)]}; sys2 = 
 Flatten[Numerator[
    Together[
     ComplexExpand[ReIm[sys] /. Equal -> Subtract, {rho, s, A, B}, 
      TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]] /. 0 -> Nothing];
Solve[Join[sys2, {Im[rho]}] == 0, Re[rho], MaxExtraConditions -> 3]`

Comment: You had what I believe is an intended typo there at `ReIm[sys]`in
`sys = {rho == s + 1/(1 - A/B), 
  s + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s + 1/(1 - B/A)]}; sys2 = 
 Flatten[Numerator[
    Together[
     ComplexExpand[Re[sys] /. Equal -> Subtract, {rho, s, A, B}, 
      TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]] /. 0 -> Nothing]; Solve[
 Join[sys2, {Im[rho]}] == 0, Re[rho], MaxExtraConditions -> 3]`
But changing it to `Re[sys]` gives interesting output.

Comment: As well as: `sys = {rho == s + 1/(1 - A/B), 
  s + 1/(1 - A/B) == Conjugate[-s + 1/(1 - B/A)]}; sys2 = 
 Flatten[Numerator[
    Together[
     ComplexExpand[Im[sys] /. Equal -> Subtract, {rho, s, A, B}, 
      TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]] /. 0 -> Nothing]; Solve[
 Join[sys2, {Im[rho]}] == 0, Im[rho], MaxExtraConditions -> 3]` with `Im[sys]` in the middle.

Comment: Nevermind, I found this now: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html My Mathematica version is too old. I should update.